# Imagem no printDocument_PrintPage

Tags: c#, imagem, impressora

Como inserir imagem em um formulário de impressão, tipo como acontece no caso do **icon** lá quando estou editando o`form`,
a unica maneira que acabei achando foi através de

`Image IMG = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\Imagem.Extenção");`

Assim ela tem que se deslocar com o programa, quando mudado de pasta, queria ela já salva junto/dentro de seu `.exe`

Comment: o que voce ta usando aí? Winforms? pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer o upload dessa imagem para a aplicação e depois utilizá-la para impressão correto ?

Comment: exato, agora a unica maneira que tenho pra "chamar" é como mencionei acima. Estou usando WinForms